# c# web api 2 pass dictionary to upload endpoint

Tags: c#, multipartform-data

Currently I have this endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{containerName}/{reference}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Document))]
    [ClaimsAuthorization(ClaimName = "Administrator")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateAsync(string containerName, string reference) => Ok(await _provider.CreateAsync(Request, containerName, reference));
```

Which, as you can see, has some parameters that are part of the **path** for my upload controller. I would like to send a `Dictionary<string, string>` to this method. Is it possible?

For illustration purposes, this is how I am trying to call my endpoint:

```
function save(containerName, reference, file, metadata, onComplete) {
    var message;
    if (!containerName) message = 'You must supply a container name.';
    if (!reference) message ='You must supply a reference.';
    if (!file) message = 'No file was provided.';
    if (message) { 
        ngNotify.set(message, { type: 'warn' });
        return $q.reject(message);
    }

    var url = apiUrl + 'documents/' + containerName + '/' + reference;
    var formData = new FormData();            
    var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }
    };

    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('metadata', metadata);

    return $http(request).then(function (response) {
        SimpleCache.remove(apiUrl + '/documents');
        listDirectiveService.refresh('file');
        ngNotify.set('Your document was created.');
    }, notifications.handleError).finally(function () {                
        onComplete();
    });
}
```

Comment: What is up with `[ResponseType(typeof(Document))]`...? Return a strongly typed value instead

Comment: https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send a Dictionary to this method. It is possible to send the data in the form body or in the query string, but sending it in the form body avoids URL encoding issues and URL length limits.

To see what the dictionary would look like as JSON, serialize a dictionary to JSON. For example:

```
var dictionary = {
  "Item 1": "Value 1",
  "Item 2": "Value 2",
  "Item 3": "Value 3"
}
formData.append('dictionary', JSON.stringify(dictionary));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FromBody` annotation to define a property that should be passed in the body of the request:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{containerName}/{reference}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Document))]
[ClaimsAuthorization(ClaimName = "Administrator")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateAsync(string containerName, string reference, [FromBody] Dictionary<string,string> myDictionary)
```